# Selecting a specific access FORM from two combo boxes

Tags: winforms, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table for machinery items which has many columns. In order to enable the users to enter specific information without confusion I divided the columns into some forms based on type and sub-type fields in the table. For example type1 and subtype1 have specific columns and they are kept in a type1-subtype1 form and type2 and sub-type2 in type2-subtype2 form and so on. **I have a total of 5 types and 5 subtypes, so I have a total of 25 forms.** I used two combo boxes in a new form for type and subtype as given in the figure, **I want to select type from type combo and sub-type from sub-type combo and when I click the open form button IT SHOULD DISPLAY THE RESPECTIVE FORM**.[image: enter image d escription here]
 For example if the user selects type5 from type combo and subtype3 from subtype combo then type5-subtype3 form should be displayed and so on for all the 25 forms. I tried playing around the [on click] embedded macro for the open form button, but in vain. Is it ever possible to do this in this method in access or please suggest a method. It would be very helpful for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are those 25 forms really so much different that you can't use a single form with data controls which are enabled/disabled based on the  current type/subtype combination?  I would try hard to find a way to avoid the need for so many separate forms.

Comment: Absolutely! 25 forms is excessive.

Comment: @HansUp It is a worthy point..I will work to reduce the number of forms..thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT* changed combo box property from **Selected** to **Value**

Sometimes are limited and won't let you set a property as a string.  Looks like this might be one of those cases.  If so, you can always use Visual Basic ("Code Builder") instead of an embedded macro.  Inside the Click handler, something like this:

```
Dim formName As String
formName = type.Value & "-" & subtype.Value
DoCmd.OpenForm formName
```

Comment: The combo's `.Selected` property requires you supply a `Row` argument.    Perhaps you meant its `.Value` property instead.

Comment: @dbaseman  Thank you very much for the reply, should I type in the above code in between the private sub button_click() and end or should i do it for each form. Sorry I am new to visual basic, very sorry for such a naive question. I appreciate your help....

Comment: Good.  Though `.Value` isn't strictly required there because it's the default property.  I think the OP actually wants something like `formName = "type" & type.Value & "-" & "subtype" & subtype.Value`

Comment: @alex, yes, that code goes in the body of private sub button_click().  As HansUp points out, you will need to tweak the "formName" line to your needs (depends on what names/values are actually in the combo box)